# How to set checkbox in Mission Control?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to set checkbox in Mission Control pane in System Preferences. So far I'm able to open MC but I have no idea how to click on checkbox. I tried everything I found on Internet but with no luck...
How can I do it?

> tell application "System Preferences"     activate    set current pane to
>   pane "com.apple.preference.expose" end tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will click the first checkbox of the pane only if it is currently not checked:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.expose"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        set firstCheckbox to checkbox 1 of group 2 of window 1
        set checked to value of firstCheckbox as boolean
        if (not checked) then
            click firstCheckbox
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```